# Postfix Perl mailing via PostDrop

Tags: perl, email, postfix-mta

I'm trying to inject an email directly into the postfix queue using a perl module Mail::Postfix::Postdrop which ultilises a postfix method of allowing messages to be written directly to the postdrop directory.

There is a small amount of documentation which has enabled me to send a message successfully, however, I am confused to how I am able to set a subject and message body. An attempt to set the variable $message does little to nothing.

I must admit, I'm an apprentice to Perl at best, I would appreciate any help.

```
#Code which successfully sends an email:
    use Mail::Postfix::Postdrop 'inject';   
      $message = 'test message';
      inject $message, Sender     => 'postmaster@mydomain.com',
                       Recipients => [ qw(email@someotherdomain.com) ];
```

Some relavant documentation:
http://annocpan.org/~PMAKHOLM/Mail-Postfix-Postdrop-0.3/lib/Mail/Postfix/Postdrop.pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In email messages "headers" section is separated from "body" section by empty line. Just change your $message to:

```
$message = "Subject: This is my subject!\n\nAnd this is my message";
```

and you should see that you've set subject and message text. Note "\n\n", which creates empty line (double quotes are used to allow \n interpolation in $message).

Note that Mail::Postfix::Postdrop claims it accepts Email::Abstract object as a message, so you might consider using Email::Simple (or other Email::Abstract supporting class) to create your messages.